# Following a link in a Hover Menu

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have a horizontal menu with a dropdown div on the first menu item.

http://jsfiddle.net/2dPXY/

I want the first link "Find a Doctor" to still be click-able, so someone can either choose from the dropdown, or just click the link.

Right now it's not clickable, and I can't figure out why. I tried adding the following to my jquery file, but it didn't work:

(This is also in the jfiddle above)

```
      $("#menu li a").click(
        function () {
          console.log($(this).html());
          window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
        }
      );
```

Any idea why I can't click on a link that has a dropdown and how to fix it?

Comment: The links are with # anchors: `<a href="#">Acupuncture</a>`

Comment: each id is supposed to be unique within the document, you have a ton of violations of that.  You should probably use classes instead.

Comment: @ShankarCabus That actually isn't the issue here.  I saw that myself, but clicking on the main link still doesn't work.

Comment: The # anchor links are working fine, the "Find a Doctor" link should link to doctor.php and it does not. 
Also, I am aware of the ID vs. CLASS issues, and they'll be fixed after this gets working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `.submenu` div is positioned on top of the tabs, so it's intercepting the click.  (I found that it was positioned over the tabs by setting a 10-pixel red border).  All you have to do to fix this is use a `top` of 30px instead of a `margin-top` in `#catmenu`.

See my updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q9A9T/

Answer (score 0):

The `.submenu` is over the link.

Tips:
1) IDs must be unique to not cause conflict.

2) This is unnecessary:

```
  $("#menu li").hover(
    function () {
      $("a#menulink", this).css('color','#39c')
      .next('.submenu').css('display','block');
    }
  );
```

Use only CSS:

```
#menuli:hover #menulink{
    color: #39c;
}

#menuli:hover .submenu{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: The :hover pseudoclass isn't supported on older versions of IE with anything other than the <a> tag, so I used jquery to get the hover on LI support in IE.
Once you world gives up on older versions of IE, I agree yours is more elegant and would have used it myself.

Comment: @Michelle, are you sure that you need support IE6 and IE7 (1,5%)?? I would not! http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201108-201208

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that 1.5% includes several of our clients!

Answer (score 0):

You can add to in the css to the `ul#menu a#menulink`-ID's `z-index:1;` and it will work!
See here: http://jsfiddle.net/2dPXY/4/

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but I used the answer above. Thanks!